# How to change data format?

Tags: php, highcharts

I am using highcharts.js. I want to draw basic line chart. For that, data format is like: `data: [12, 34, 56, 76, 78, 78]`.
I have database value. my value format is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [sum] => 1820 [ay] => October ) [1] => Array ( [sum] => 3144 [ay] => November ) )
```

I need sum values. I wrote some codes to take sum values.

```
$data5 = array();
foreach ($result5 as $row)  {$data5[] = $row;}

foreach($data5 as $dat)
{
$date .=$dat['sum'];
}
echo $date;
```

I have two values for sum value. First value is: 1820, second value is: 3144. but when I write $date (`echo $date`) just showing: 18203144.

Where I do mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `array_push()` method instead. What you're doing now is appending a string together ... you want an array of values instead.

Try this and see whether this gives you the desired result:

```
$sumData = array();
foreach($data5 as $dat) {
    array_push($sumData, $dat['sum']);
}
echo $sumData;
```

I hope this is helpful for you.